# Android-PC Connection

Tags: usb, android

After connecting my Ubuntu PC with a Vivo Android device using a USB cable, I keep getting this response(Image attached). Help, thank you!.

[image]

Comment: What were you trying to do before this error occured?

Comment: @Freax You mean apart from the connection..?

Comment: Yes, It will be easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Freax Nothing. I just plugged in my USB cable and accessed the Files app.

Comment: Do you only get this error during the Android-Pc connection or it occurs when you open the nautilus application. Actually, this error happens when some background processes crash.

Comment: Please add the output of "ps ax | grep nautilus" in your question.

Comment: With other devices, the USB connection works just fine. It's just the Vivo device. @Freax